# Clickable area bigger than imageButton

Tags: android

I got an ImageButton which's clickable area needs to be bigger than just the image itself, I do, however, want to constraint that button on the left to a text box... I've looked through similar questions but couldn't find an answer that helps.
This is the code rn:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/skipButton"
    android:layout_width="42dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:onClick="onSkipButtonPressed"
    android:padding="0px"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:scaleX="0.5"
    android:scaleY="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/hintTextView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.989"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/skip_button_selector" />
```

And here's an image of what the contraints look like...
[image: How the button should connect to the box]

I hope this is enough info to help with this issue. I'm rather lost with it tbh.
Thank you very much!

Comment: nothing to do with android studio, everything to do with android :) don't use the IDE tag for questions regarding android, only use the IDE tag if you're asking about the IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just increase the padding and size of your image

```
<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/skipButton"
android:layout_width="60dp"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:background="@null"
android:onClick="onSkipButtonPressed"
android:padding="10dp"
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
android:scaleX="0.5"
android:scaleY="0.5"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/hintTextView"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.989"
app:srcCompat="@drawable/skip_button_selector/>
```

also you can use paddingEnd and paddingBottom attributes it will not change position of your image but increase the area

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/skipButton"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:onClick="onSkipButtonPressed"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:scaleX="0.5"
    android:scaleY="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/hintTextView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.989"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/skip_button_selector/>
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer but wouldn't that change the image's size?

Comment: @KonstiLackner if you look my code I increased the size with 20 and padding with 10 so your image size will not change but your image button size will

Comment: Okok, so if I wanted to make the button even bigger, I'd just need to change both of the values accordingly? Is it a problem that one of them is px and the other dp?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work... The clickable area is still just the image (for both versions)

Comment: @KonstiLackner yes and according to your position of image or image button you can just increase the value of width height along with paddingEnd+paddingBottom or paddingStart+paddingTop or individual padding to avoid repositioning of image

Comment: Ok so width and height set the clickable area whereas padding is just for moving the button? because with 
android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
and
android:paddingStart="20dp"
The button just gets smaller and the clickable box doesn't seem bigger

Comment: @KonstiLackner yes it (clickable area)depends of height and width where as padding used to position inner contain w.r.t. its boundaries (height and width)